# Random Playing Cards Generation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to create a simple texas hold'em poker game in unity, I have 52 sprites (images) of each card in a deck

i am trying to load player cards in the beginning of a round, (2 cards for each player) for n number of players all respective to 52 cards in the deck.

so what i am trying to do, is first generate a random number and then based on that number, i load the specific sprite but my unity freezes and nothing works and i am aware that this approach will not work if i replicate my Card Prefab which is bound with Get_Card Class, So i need another Approach. HELP thanks

Random Number Class

```
public class Random_Number
{
   const int n = 52;
    int[] all_num = new int[n];
    int number = 0;


    void Start()
    {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        all_num[i] = i;
    }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public int get_me_a_number()
    {


        while (number == 0)
            {
            int rand = Random.Range(0, n);
            number = all_num[rand];
            all_num[rand] = 0;
            }

        Debug.Log(number.ToString());
        return number;
    }
}
```

Card Class

```
public class Get_Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] Sprite_pic;
    int number;
    Random_Number number_class = new Random_Number();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

            number = number_class.get_me_a_number();
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite_pic[number];


    }
```

ISSUE is now fixed, Freezing issue was caused by an infinite loop.

Comment: Is Random_Number Start definitely being called to initialise all_num? Your code will also lock once you've dealt all 52 cards: you could get get_me_a_number to spot when all_num is all zeros and reshuffle the deck.

Comment: `number` in `Random_Number` is a class member so you will return the same card everytime because you are not resetting it back to zero. (Probably not related to freezing)

Comment: stop you change the question...ist not good;, the answers dont link to the new question about infinite loop.. please repost the last question and opene a new..but dont chaneg the problem

Comment: @Frenchy ok bro

Comment: if you want to increase the random generation use a shuffle algorithm https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrHCuw

Comment: @SilentHG no problem its done to keep rules on SO and avoid confusion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case in class Random_Number

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        all_num[i] = i;
    }
}
```

is never called..so all_num is an array of Zero value (-> infinite loop in while)

i suppose you want to call it when the Class is instanciated

so i suggest you to declare a constructor:

```
public Random_number()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        all_num[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks, the issue is over now.

Comment: its no good and no pleasant to change the problem in same post..please close your question by validating an answer (and load your initial problem of infinite loop) and post new question

Answer (score 2):

`Start()` and `Update()` is Unity event function, and will be called by unity automatically **who inherits `MonoBehaviour`, and attached to active gameobject**. In your code, your class `Random_Number` doesn't inherit `Monobehaviour`, so `Start()` is nothing more than just a method, which will never be called without the caller.

Because the default value of uninitialized `int` is `0` and `Start()` is never called, every element of `all_num` is zero. So when you call `get_me_a_number()`, what you are doing is just

```
while (0 == 0)
{
    // assign 0 to 0
}
```

Which is basically *infinite-loop*. That's why your unity stops.

Here's my suggestion: Initialize `Random_Number` with the explicit constructor:

```cs
public Random_number()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        all_num[i] = i;
    }
}
```